# how to move window across multiple screens with mouse without borders

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

okay so I have two windows 7 laptops, have mouse without borders on both and have it all setup, my keyboard and mouse are connected to both laptops. Only problem is that I can't drag the windows across the two screens, any idea why this is?

Comment: What does mouse 'without borders' mean?

Comment: I presumed this: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35460

Answer (score 3):

I don't know this particular product, but I can't imagine this is possible. 
You will be able to share your mouse and keyboard across the separate computers and may be able to share a clipboard as this is just data and can be transferred.

However, dragging a window from one machine would involve moving the running process from one machine to another, which is not possible.

If you want to run multiple screens on one machine and move windows from one to another this is as simple as plugging a second monitor (not a second laptop) in.

Answer (score 0):

Mouse without borders is used control multiple computers with the mouse and keyboard connected to one of those computers. also allows you to share clipboard and drag and drop files.  But is different with applications. Your application is running on one of the computers, you can't move it to the other computer just by dragging it. The program is running consuming memory, files and possibly other resources from the first computer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).